# Crazy IIS Error With MVC and <location> element

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I am trying to gain some insight into what causes a particularly odd error I have been seeing. I have isolated the issue as follows:

Create an ASP.Net MVC application with a two basic controllers.

```
public class HasLocationController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
}

public class NoLocationController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

Add a location element to the web.config for the path 'HasLocation'

```
<location path="HasLocation">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Publish the site to IIS6 or IIS7 **(IISExpress and WebDevServer won't work)**, and attempt to browse using the following links:

```
http://[yourdomain]/NoLocation/%20~C:/blah.txt

http://[yourdomain]/HasLocation/%20~C:/blah.txt
```

For the controller that has no corresponding location element configured, you get the kind of exception message you would expect.

---

[image: Exception From Controller Without Location Element]

---

However, if you attempt the same thing on the controller with the location element, then you get this strange error:

**NOTE:** This only happens with the leading tilde (~) character. Without that, you get the normal error you would expect.

---

[image: Error When Using Location Element]

---

I haven't been able to really find documentation regarding this error, but I am very interested to understand why this is happening, and how to prevent it.

ANY light you could shed on the issue would be helpful.

Comment: @DarthVader - Are you being serious? 74% is pretty good... and I don't ask questions very often. They usually go unanswered for a reason.

Comment: Curious. Do you get the same error if you url encode the tilde (%7e)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are virtually hundreds of answers on the internet regarding this *error*.  Most likely it has nothing to do at all with your controllers but with:

> ~C:/blah.txt

Specifically the `:` Which it probably finds as being potentially dangerous.  Take a look at [HttpRuntimeSection.RequestPathInvalidCharacters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx).

As for the second error. It is correct, the directory `HasLocation` does not exist in your project.  When it is created, you will get the first error.  When you remove the `:` it will attempt to load whatever file you requestion in the `HasLocation` directory.

**NOTE: You MUST NOT use the location element in the web.config to security MVC application controllers, you need to use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.authorizationattribute(v=vs.91).aspx) or other custom attributes like it.**

[Here is a Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2010/08/24/securing-your-mvc-application.aspx) and any search of SO or Google will pretty much say the same thing:

> You cannot use routing or web.config files to secure your MVC application. The only supported way to secure your MVC application is to use a base class with an [Authorize] attribute,  and then have each controller type subclass that base type.

Restate of whats happening:

**First Error**: Your URL is throwing an error due to the [HttpRuntimeSection.RequestPathInvalidCharacters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx).

**Second Error**: It doesn't matter if you have controllers or not.  The default ASP.Net Webforms engine is trying to detect if a directory exists as you specified in the url (in your case a directory called *HasDirectory*) because it needs to authorize the directory access for the Webforms engine as you specified in the web.config location element.  It's not even worried about the file yet.  Since this directory doesn't exist, you get the error  exactly as your image states (I've highlighted in green):

[image: Highlighted Error]

If you create the directory, then you get error #1.

The entire ASP.Net runtime does something like this:

1. Parse the Path necessary for the request.
2. Validate any Authorization to the directory if it exists in the web.config location element.
3. If it has access, get the file and parse it for whatever it is (aspx, etc)
4. If the it doesn't have access **AND** the file exists throw an exception or redirect as configured.
5. If the **file does NOT exist**, ignore the location element in web.config and run the [IIS catch all](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/21/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) to determine if there is [another route for the request](http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/gopalk/archive/2009/01/20/how-does-asp-net-mvc-work.aspx).

Comment: The initial error yes, there are hundreds of resources regarding the potentially dangerous request path, but the second error... not so much. It **only** happens when there is a `<location>` element in place that corresponds to that Route, and **only** when prefixed with the tilde `~` It seems to be very specific, but for some reason follows a different route because of it.

Comment: Wait.. you want to know why you get an error with an Empty controller?

Comment: The controller isn't really empty. I guess that is a bit of a misnomer. What I mean is that it has a single action `Index()` that returns a nearly empty view. That really doesn't matter so much though because it never makes it to the controller.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem, although I'm running IISExpress which is technically almost the same as IIS.

Comment: The problem doesn't show up in IISExpress, or the WebDevServer. You specifically have to publish to an IIS instance... easiest to just publish locally.

Comment: And you tried it with the URL: `localhost/HasLocation/~c:/blah.txt`

Comment: I understand the issue with using the location element, and that it is not a good idea. I'll certainly give you a +1 for going the distance, but I really just want to know *what* is happening to cause the difference in behavior. Call it academic intrigue. Either way, I really want to understand the nuts and bolts what what is actually happening, and why simply prefixing the path with a tilde causes the other error? Why does that one extra character force it down another path?

Comment: "You MUST NOT use..." Can you supply a reference here?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I at least want to thank you for all the effort you put into the anwer on here, and I'm going to mark yours as correct. However, I am well aware of the advice regarding security issues. For some background I am working in a hybrid webforms/mvc site. Otherwise this wouldn't be an issue. Also, I *still* don't understand why the second error *only* shows up when using a physical path, prefixed with a tilde. It's just very odd. I understand pretty much everything else, but not *that*. Regardless, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the tilde in the url is tricking the Virtual Path Provider into looking for that controller on the physical disk.